# Does cron @reboot run before systemd?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, cron, systemd

A command defined as *@reboot* in the root *crontab* runs before or after *systemd* services?

Is it random or OS dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs can only start when the cron daemon is running, and of course systemd starts the cron daemon like every other service.

If it is important to run a specific job before or after something else, consider using a systemd timer/service to schedule it.